# How can I make a square spiral (curve) in Geometry Nodes 3.4

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: square spiral]

I used discrete curve lines connected to each other but in the end it created a boundary between them. In the picture, I added *Curve to Mesh* with *Curve Circle*

[image]

[image]

I sincerely apologize that my nodes are so messy and unclear. But basically I'm trying to *Instance on Points* the new *Curve Lines* to the end points of the original *Curve Lines* and rotate it $90°$.

I hope there is a way to make a single curve with a square spiral shape!

Answer (score 8):

You can solve the task with the following setup:

[image]

Here I use a mathematical setup based purely on the index of a spline and some math nodes.

I calculate a specific position in the positive or negative range for each point on both axes.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Another approach using instancing.

The spiral is composed of 'corners':

- on the upper left part they are growing from 2, 4, 6 etc.
- on the lower right part they are growing from 1, 3, 5 etc.

The setup combines these two corner 'arrays' and merge them.

[image]

[image]